# Cascading styles change in angular4+

Tags: angular

```
// component parent - template
<div class="parent">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>


// somewhere in the code
<parent>
    <label>Some Text</label>
</parent>
```

As in the style of the parent component to set the color for the label?

```
.parent label
    color: red
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify styles for elements which will go in `ng-content` in parent of `parent` component. And for everything else - in `parent` component.
Please have a look on the [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4A1kLY?p=preview)